# Share the same Unity container across MVC, WebAPI, and WebForms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webforms, unity-container

**Issue**

The title probably doesn't use the correct terminology, but I think you should be able to figure out what I mean: I want to register the same services for use across all three technologies in the same project. I've read that it is possible to use Unity in a project with both MVC and Web API. But my project is a bit more interesting than that.

**Background**

I have a legacy (ancient) Webforms project running on .NET 4.7.2. We are actively working on converting the whole thing to Angular. The final goal being to convert to .NET Core/.NET 5 -- having only the Angular project and Web API in the final solution. My plan is to convert each `.aspx` page to an Angular component(s) and replace all the code-behind data access to Web API calls, one-at-a-time as I touch them. We are only using ASP.NET MVC to make it easier to authenticate/authorize against our IdentityServer 4 implementation.

**What I know so far**

I'm pretty sure I need to install the following three packages to get DI working in all three:

- `Unity.Mvc`
- `Unity.AspNet.WebApi`
- `AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity`

I've seen articles that describe how to use Unity with both ASP.NET MVC and Web API in the same project. But I'm still a little fuzzy on the whole thing.

**Question**

How do I wire up Unity for all three (ASP.NET MVC, Web API and Webforms) and register my services once for all three?

Comment: Wire up each one...just use the same container instead of separate container instances. I suggest you actually give it a try. If you run into a problem with your implementation, then show your code and clearly explain what's not working about it.

Comment: @mason this was the answer in a roundabout way. See my response below...

Answer (score 0):

Alright well I've got Unity working in all three technologies.
`Unity.Mvc` and `Unity.AspNet.WebApi` were easy since they both share the same *scaffolded* `UnityConfig` class in my project. The `UnityConfig` class creates the `UnityContainer` and keeps a `static` reference to it.

This package: `AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity` is no longer maintained and has some problems (project doesn't compile with this referenced). But I found an article (which I cannot find the URL to) that said to use `HouseofCat.DependencyInjection.WebForms` which at least compiles. However it creates its own instance of `UnityContainer`. So I had to look at what that code was doing and adapt it to reference the shared container from my `UntityConfig`.

Now I've got ctor injection in my API Controllers, MVC and WebForms. And I only have to register services once.